# Parsing dataset from GitHub

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Is there any problem related to Johns Hopkins data set in GitHub?
In particular when I'm trying to parse the CSV file of updated cases and I receive the error : HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

```
import pandas as pd
main_link = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/'
CONFIRMED = pd.read_csv(main_link+'time_series_19-covid-Confirmed.csv')
DEATHS = pd.read_csv(main_link+'time_series_19-covid-Deaths.csv')
RECOVERED = pd.read_csv(main_link+'time_series_19-covid-Recovered.csv')
```

Comment: Well like the error says, the URL is not valid. It is not with the parsing, but with *fetching* the dataset.

Comment: Thank you Willem for your answer , I tried to modify it with a valid url, but I still receive the same error

Comment: Works for me with the correct url.

Answer (score 4):

The links in your program are invalid. Checking the official Github, the url below is one you're looking for:

[COVID 19 Confirmed Global](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv)

Comment: good day dar Linny - many thanks for the update - this is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you should do it:

```py
import pandas as pd
import io
import requests
CONFIRMED_CONTENT = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv').content
CONFIRMED = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(CONFIRMED_CONTENT.decode('utf-8')))
print(CONFIRMED)
```

And you will see that confirm has all the data:

```
                  Province/State         Country/Region       Lat       Long  1/22/20  1/23/20  1/24/20  1/25/20  1/26/20  1/27/20  1/28/20  1/29/20  1/30/20  ...  3/26/20  3/27/20  3/28/20  3/29/20  3/30/20  3/31/20  4/1/20  4/2/20  4/3/20  4/4/20  4/5/20  4/6/20  4/7/20
0                            NaN            Afghanistan  33.00000  65.000000        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0  ...       94      110      110      120      170      174     237     273     281     299     349     367     423
1                            NaN                Albania  41.15330  20.168300        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0  ...      174      186      197      212      223      243     259     277     304     333     361     377     383
2                            NaN                Algeria  28.03390   1.659600        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0  ...      367      409      454      511      584      716     847     986    1171    1251    1320    1423    1468
3                            NaN                Andorra  42.50630   1.521800        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0  ...      224      267      308      334      370      376     390     428     439     466     501     525     545
4                            NaN                 Angola -11.20270  17.873900        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0  ...        4        4        5        7        7        7       8       8       8      10      14      16      17
..                           ...                    ...       ...        ...      ...      ...      ...      ...      ...      ...      ...      ...      ...  ...      ...      ...      ...      ...      ...      ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
258  Falkland Islands (Malvinas)         United Kingdom -51.79630 -59.523600        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0  ...        0        0        0        0        0        0       0       0       0       1       2       2       2
259    Saint Pierre and Miquelon                 France  46.88520 -56.315900        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0  ...        0        0        0        0        0        0       0       0       0       0       1       1       1
260                          NaN            South Sudan   6.87700  31.307000        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0  ...        0        0        0        0        0        0       0       0       0       0       1       1       2
261                          NaN         Western Sahara  24.21550 -12.885800        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0  ...        0        0        0        0        0        0       0       0       0       0       4       4       4
262                          NaN  Sao Tome and Principe   0.18636   6.613081        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        0  ...        0        0        0        0        0        0       0       0       0       0       0       4       4

[263 rows x 81 columns]
```