# Pandas read_csv HTTPError: not Found

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm getting an HTTPError: not Found error when using pandas read_csv.

Typing the link into a browser I can access the CSV, when using read_csv it returns HTTP Error, so I know the file and url exists.

Previously, this code was working, but after changing python versions, it stopped. I have a feeling it is something to do with creating the URL / URL request, but cannot determine.

Pandas ver 1.2.5,
Python ver 3.9.12

```
import pandas as pd

url= r'http://fc3eqrp01:8000/data/SimulationOutputFilesNewModel_ShortTerm/s2outs.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url)



Traceback (most recent call last):

  File E:\PythontoSQL\Save S2Outs\Save_S2Outs.py:13 in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv(url)

  File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py:610 in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

  File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py:462 in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)

  File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py:819 in __init__
    self._engine = self._make_engine(self.engine)

  File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py:1050 in _make_engine
    return mapping[engine](self.f, **self.options)  # type: ignore[call-arg]

  File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py:1867 in __init__
    self._open_handles(src, kwds)

  File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py:1362 in _open_handles
    self.handles = get_handle(

  File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py:558 in get_handle
    ioargs = _get_filepath_or_buffer(

  File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py:289 in _get_filepath_or_buffer
    req = urlopen(filepath_or_buffer)

  File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py:195 in urlopen
    return urllib.request.urlopen(*args, **kwargs)

  File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\urllib\request.py:214 in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)

  File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\urllib\request.py:523 in open
    response = meth(req, response)

  File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\urllib\request.py:632 in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(

  File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\urllib\request.py:561 in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)

  File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\urllib\request.py:494 in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)

  File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\urllib\request.py:641 in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)

HTTPError: Not Found
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `file://` prefix instead of http or try `read_html`[source](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html). If the csv is located on a server that you need access to, perhaps you need to send in request headers. I'll also add that you could try this approach:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61110214/8564439.

Comment: Thank you very much, i did try the file:// , but i think it may be only supported from localhost. I will try the others